# Change contents of div, on <a> click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to implement this type of behaviour:

on the left side of the page, there is a navigation with links, and on the right side of the page there is a blank div. When user clicks on link, content on the right changes. Same should happen with all other links.

My question would be, what is the best way to achieve this? I was thinking about JQuery tabs, and just style tab's title to look like a link, but there is a gap between these two divs, so I guess it is impossible.

Comment: do you have a sample code you are working with ?

Comment: Not yet actually. I just have a Tab where navigation should appear. Pretty much what I ask is how to achieve div's content changing on <a> click.

Comment: Yes, the best form is use jQuery UI Tabs, https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax click in "view code" and load the content with ajax. Is very simple to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use jQuery tabs for that.

Take in mind, that SF isn't a source of scripts, so, you should try something before and post your doubt after with some code to be analysed for whose maybe will help you.

You have many alternatives to do that, but, based in what you said. I undestood that you want do it only with javascript, right?

So, you can use jQuery like this to achieve that.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#left-side a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({url: $(this).data('target'), dataType: 'html', success: function(result){
            $("#right-side").html(result);
        }});
        return false;
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div id='left-side'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#' data-target='aa.html'>Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' data-target='page2.html'>Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' data-target='page2.html'>Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id='right-side'>
</div>
```

Every time you click on some link, this script will load the defined page with ajax. I suggest you to use server side to achieve this, but, this also works.

Hope it helps you.